# Web Components - extend native element's style

Tags: html, css, web-component, native-web-component

I would like to extend the native button element but I am not sure how to add styling. In Google's example [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements#extendhtml) they don't use a template so the `fancy-button` custom element itself is the button, rather than adding a template and shadow DOM containing a button element. It seems to defeat the object of extending a native element if I just add a button directly to the shadow DOM, but I don't know how to style and extend native element. How can I create a custom element which is simply the native button element extended to have a red background?

```
var style = `button { background-color: red; };
class FancyButton extends HTMLButtonElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
customElements.define('fancy-button', FancyButton, {extends: 'button'});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. since you don't have shadowDOM involved you can use global CSS
2. you can set styles in the connectedCallback: `this.style.background='red'`
3. you can dynamically create a STYLE tag with unique identifier scoping your element

See JSFiddle for all 3 examples: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/gohzwvL4/

> Important is the notation for your **Customized Built-In Element**

**Correct :** `<button is="fancy-button></button>`

**InCorrect:** `<fancy-button></fancy-button>`  (this is Autonomous Element notation)

.

#### Firefox pitfall:

The **INcorrect** notation works in Firefox , but **not** in Chrome & Opera

Firefox processes **Extended Built-In Elements** with **Autonomous Element** notation
but **only** for elements created in the DOM **prior** to definition:

This

```html
<fancy-button>Hello Fancy Red Button #1</fancy-button>

<script>
    class FancyButton extends HTMLButtonElement {
        constructor() {
            super();
        }

        connectedCallback() {
            this.style.background = 'red';
        }
    }

    customElements.define('fancy-button', FancyButton, { extends: 'button' });
</script>

<fancy-button>Hello Fancy Red Button #2</fancy-button>
```

is displayed in Firefox as:

[image]

> - any number of Custom Elements **before** the `SCRIPT` tag are colored!
> - When the `<SCRIPT>` is moved into the `<HEAD>` Firefox won't color any background
> - When the script is executed after the `onload` event **all** buttons are colored

This is non-standard behaviour!

Comment: Changing `innerText` of a component using an appended style sheet removes the stylesheet. https://jsfiddle.net/yj6Lg3w2/4/

Comment: Yes. it is the same behaviour as having just one <STYLE> tag inside a <BODY> and then doing ``document.body.innerHTML=''Bye! Bye! STYLE"; `` So ``this.shadowRoot.innerHTML="Bye!"`` will overwrite the whole shadowDOM. There is no <HEAD> section inside shadowDOM to safely apply styles. **adoptedStylesheets** could be a future feature: https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/4835 (Chrome only for now)