# Allow textarea web component to accept inner text

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, native-web-component

I am building a web component which uses the `<textarea>` element, but I cannot work out how to make it accept inner text like the native `<textarea>` element.

```
<body>
  <textarea>this works</textarea>
  <expanding-textarea>this doesn't</expanding-textarea>
  <script type="module">
    const template = document.createElement("template");
    template.innerHTML = `<textarea></textarea>`;

    class ExpandingTextarea extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
      }
    }
    customElements.define("expanding-textarea", ExpandingTextarea);
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `contentEditable` attribute on the element?

Comment: Whilst this doesn't answer the question, I have not come across contentEditable before - it is very interesting, thanks. However, note the spec is not expected to move past it's current draft stage https://w3c.github.io/editing/contentEditableTrue.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the textContent property of the newly created textarea in your constructor.
I made a simplified version for you.

```
class ExpandingTextarea extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textarea.textContent = this.textContent;
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(textarea);
  }
}
customElements.define("expanding-textarea", ExpandingTextarea);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 types of Custom Elements

- Autonomous Custom Elements (extend from (root) HTMLElement, like the first answer)
- Customized Buil-In Elements (extend from existing elements)

So you can extend from **HTMLTextAreaElement** and get all functionality for free:

```js
  class MyTextArea extends HTMLTextAreaElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.placeholder = 'Type some text';
      this.cols = 60;
      this.rows = 10;
    }
  }

  customElements.define('my-textarea', MyTextArea, { extends: 'textarea' });
```

```html
<textarea is=my-textarea></textarea>
```

**Important Notes:**

- Opera & Safari do **not** support Customized Built-In Elements yet, there is a [polyfill](https://github.com/ungap/custom-elements-builtin)
- Customized Built-In Textarea (because of its inner workings) can **not** have a shadowDOM
  most other Customized Built-In Elements can have a shadowDOM
- You dynamically create a Customized Built-In Element with:
  `document.createElement( "textarea", {is:"my-textarea"} )`
- Firefox **incorrectly!!** allows `<my-textarea></my-textarea>` notation, [when defining elements late](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59431342/web-components-extend-native-elements-style/59435638#59435638)