# is it possible to use slot with attachShadow for a textarea?

Tags: textarea, shadow-dom, custom-element

Is there some way of using `<slot>` with `<textarea>` when creating a custom shadowDom element?

As per the standard (& I guess expected) textarea behaviour it's content is escaping `<slot></slot>` to `&lt;slot&gt;&lt;/slot&gt;`

If I run the following

```html
    <script>
        window.customElements.define('my-textarea',
            class MyButton extends HTMLElement {
                constructor() {
                    super();
                    const template = document.createElement('textarea');
                    template.innerHTML = `<slot></slot>`;
                    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).appendChild(template);
                    console.log(this.shadowRoot.innerHTML);
                }
            }
        )
    </script>
    <my-textarea>i'm not used in the slot</my-textarea>
```

...then as you can see the content of the text area is displayed as `<slot></slot>` and the console logs shows the innerHTML to be `&lt;slot&gt;&lt;/slot&gt;`

Is there any technique to work around this?

-- Edit --

Just found this which is kinda similar : [Allow textarea web component to accept inner text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59455788/allow-textarea-web-component-to-accept-inner-text)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone stumbles upon this issue, for reasons I don't fully  understand (in particular why the setTimeout is necessary) the following works:

```html
<script>
    window.customElements.define('my-textarea',
        class MyTextarea extends HTMLElement {

            textarea;

            constructor() {
                super();
                this.textarea  = document.createElement('textarea');
                this.textarea.setAttribute('contentEditable','true');
                this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).appendChild(this.textarea);
            }
            connectedCallback() {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.textarea.textContent = this.textContent;
                })
            }
        }
    )
</script>
<my-textarea>for some reason this works just fine</my-textarea>
```

Comment: setTimeout is required because the connectedCallback fires on the **opening** tag, its innerHTML (lightDOM) has not been parsed yet. To wait for the content to be parsed the very sure way is the setTimeout, altnernatives require more code and gain you only microseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Note you can shorten it to:

```html
<script>
  customElements.define('my-textarea',
    class extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {
        super()        
         .attachShadow({mode:'open'})
         .append(this.textarea = document.createElement('textarea'));
      }
      connectedCallback() {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.textarea.textContent = this.textContent;
        })
      }
    })
</script>

<my-textarea>for some reason this works just fine</my-textarea>
```